# Plotly.py Merge 2 traces on the legend so they can be hidden or shown together with 1 click

Tags: python, plotly

[image: chart with an awful]

I'm trying to work out how to have a traces use just 1 entry in the legend, to save space and also so it looks better.

https://plotly.com/python/legend/#grouped-legend-items just seems to return an error on my scatter charts:

```
fig = px.scatter(df1,
                     x='Date',
                     y='Price',
                     color='Quality',
                     opacity=0.6,
                     size='Quantity',
                     size_max=60,
                     text='Text',
                     legendgroup = 'Bubbles' # Perhaps legendgroup = str( 'Quality') could work here?
                     )

TypeError: scatter() got an unexpected keyword argument 'legendgroup'
```

As you can see in the below image every number in the legend is there twice. 1 is the scatter, the other is the horizontal line. I'd like to be able to click on just 1 entry in the legend and have it hide both the scatter and the line. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do this?

I plan to turn the horizontal line into a curved line so I don't think turning the line into a shape will be a solution that will work in the future.

On a similar note, I think it would be really cool to have 'groups' of traces on the legend, e.g. 'bubbles' or 'lines', so that I could show/hide the entire group of traces at once. I reckon if the above is possible, so is this, but I wonder if it's possible to do both at once, so that I could have an on/off button for the bubbles or lines.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything or if some code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve half of this for the double click to remove both lines and bubles, but it still results in double entries in the legend.

In the add trace for the line, I simply gave it `legendgroup=str(quality)` , where quality is just the number, that seems to have done it. I don't quite understand the behaviour of why this has worked, but it's pretty much solved it.